# Protractor : Make test case wait till authentication is done

Tags: angular, promise, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I am working on an app where I load a page using browser.get('app url') then it re-routes to some different URL for authentication, prompts for credentials then goes to home page(app url), while the page completes authentication test cases starts running. The problem is that some initial test cases fail with this error *'Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.*'

I have been looking a lot around git/stackoverflow/etc but could find any help that has resolved this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to disable angular checking using `ignoreSynchronisation` option?

Comment: `browser.waitForAngular(false)` will fix this. Set it right before your `browser.get()` and then call `browser.waitForAngular(true)` when you navigate back to an angular page in your app.

Comment: it didn`t help :)

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the page and login in the onPrepare Method? Can you give more details about how your code is setup?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two try outs

- If you have been using async/await approach for the protractor test, await keyword could help your code line to wait for the previous step to finish.
- If the app in test is completely non angular, mark `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; in protractor config file.

Thanks

Comment: App is angular but the authentication process seem to be non angular, though it does not load on page.actually first test calls browser.get('app home page') which then redirects to 3rd party authorisation which prompts me a credential login, after successful login the homepage again reloads.

Comment: Did you already try this, Since the actual app is angular assuming the config browser.ignoreSynchronization is false. So just before you pass the login credentials you can change the  browser.ignoreSynchronization to true and revert it back to false after hitting login ??

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

1) Navigate to the home page
2) The page will open and reroute to a login page
3) You can send the target url ( i.e. login page URL) to a function to wait for the redirect. 
4) Once redirected set synchronization = false
5) Complete login process
6) Induce a selenium webdriver wait
7) Set synchronization = true

Here is a sample function to check if the URL has been changed. There is a wait in built in the function and will help synchronize the calls

```
waitForURLToChange(target, time) {
    console.log(target);
    let timeout = time
    return browser.driver.wait(function () {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (actualUrl) {
        console.log(actualUrl.indexOf(target));        
        return actualUrl.indexOf(target) > -1;     
      });
    }, timeout);
```

};

Comment: Say I called browser.get('app url') in the very first test case, which then automatically reroute to different login page, @Monnie_tester where am I supposed to place your your code.

Comment: Then(/^I try to login$/, async () => {
        await browser,get('url');
        await util.waitForURLToChange(); 
        await browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
 //login process here
        await browser.ignoreSynchronization = false

    });

Comment: Can you post a full example please? Perhaps update the answer with more context.

Answer (score 0):

For me, missing thing was page.navigateTo() inside beforeEach, adding it removed the issue-

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
beforeEach(async () => {
    page = new AppPage();
    page.navigateTo();
});
```